# PowerShell Insert into array

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell

We're creating a big script and need to generate some HTML-code. This all works fine and I've collected all the info I need in the array `$HTMLcode`.

I'm still a bit of a noob in array/string manipulation, so I was wondering if its possible to insert a line of text above every line in the array `HTMLcode` that starts with the text ERROR?

```
$HTMLcode=@()
$HTMLcode += "ERROR: Problem 1<br>"
$HTMLcode += "You did this wrong.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Problem 2<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Something happened here.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Porblem 3<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Did you try.. <br>"
```

Desired result would be:

```
$HTMLcode=@()
$HTMLcode += "--------------------------<br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR: Problem 1<br>"
$HTMLcode += "You did this wrong.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "--------------------------<br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Problem 2<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Something happened here.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "--------------------------<br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Porblem 3<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Did you try.. <br>"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you take care, if an operation (cmdlet) in a pipe returns two objects they will be both be placed in the pipe as separate objects.

eg.

```
2,4,6 | % { %_/2; $_ }
```

returns

```
1
2
2
4
3
6
```

Thus you could do something like:

```
$updatedHtmlCode = $HTMLCode |
       Select-Object { if ($_ -clike 'ERROR*') { '--------------------------<br>' } $_ }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Richard, but it's not really giving the desired result. It's making 6 different arrays with a comma seperator between them.. Which makes it not clean for use in HTML.

Comment: @DarkLite1 something more is going on then. Just tested `"foo","bar","bax" | % { if ($_ -eq 'bar') { "xyzzy" } $_ } | % { write-host ($i++); $_ }` and the counts clearly show the last `select-object` executes 4 times.

Comment: I'm now trying another approach which might be more readable by converting the array to a list `$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$HTMLcode)` and then insert the vallue with `$list.Insert(2,"text")`. Now I only need to figure out how to find the correct ID number `Int StartIndex`value for all text starting with ERROR, as it doesn't accept text strings.

Comment: Hi Richard, your way is indeed the best way of doing it. Thank you for your help, I marked your answer as Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found this answer:

```
$Array = @"
computer1
computer2
computer2
"@ -split "`n" | % { $_.trim() }
```

The trick is the split and trim. This makes it work down the pipeline. 
Source:
http://pleasework.robbievance.net/howto-easily-convert-block-of-text-into-an-array-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
$htmlcode = @()
$HTMLcode += "ERROR: Problem 1<br>"
$HTMLcode += "You did this wrong.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Problem 2<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Something happened here.. <br>"
$HTMLcode += "ERROR Porblem 3<br>"
$HTMLcode += "Did you try.. <br>"

$htmlcode  -replace '^(?=ERROR)',"--------------------------<br>`n"


--------------------------<br>
ERROR: Problem 1<br>
You did this wrong.. <br>
--------------------------<br>
ERROR Problem 2<br>
Something happened here.. <br>
--------------------------<br>
ERROR Porblem 3<br>
Did you try.. <br>
```

This doesn't add any additional elements to the array, it just replaces the Error lines with a new string that contains the additional text with an embedded newline before the original text.

For html, it's probably going to get sent through Out-String when you're done, and the final result should be the same as if you'd inserted new lines into the array.

Comment: Awesome! This works great too, thank you for the tip on `-replace` :)